# Check a list for specific values and if it finds replace with div

Tags: jquery, html

I am working in a project and I want to create color swatches with jQuery. 
What I am trying to accomplish is:

When the jQuery runs into a color, it must replace it with a black square. I would like though not to lose the HTML structure because I need the link.

Here is some code:

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
<dt class="even">Color</dt>
                    <dd class="even">
<ol>
    <li>
       <a href="http://scrapbooking.gr/default/shop.html?dropdown_color_of_product=96">Brown</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="">Pink</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Yellow</a>
   </li>
</ol>
</dd>
```

Imagine that this continues for long and the rest of the list is not color names. So what i tried is:

```
var color = $("#narrow-by-list dd ol li a").html();
if(color=="Black"){
  $(this).html("Code")
}
```

But the sad thing is that this doesnt work at all.

Comment: Can't understand what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` has no value and also you have no "Black" in your link list, try:

```
$("#narrow-by-list dd ol li a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    if (link.text() == "Black") {
      link.text('Code');
    }
})
```

or

```
$("#narrow-by-list dd ol li a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Black";
}).text('Code');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/95m9phku/)

Just seen your question says replace with `div` - if this is the case and not just text then change the `.text()` to `.html()`